# How to debug map only job crashing at map 97% without GUI

Tags: hadoop

I've a Map/Reduce job spread across four nodes on a cluster. I'm just ensuring the map function works currently, so I'm running the job with just a mapper. It goes from 0% to 3% to 20% etc all the way up to map 97%, reduce 0% in less than a minute, then gets stuck.

After maybe 10 minutes, the program fails, due to # of failed Map Tasks exceeding allowed limits. Usually I'd poke around on the web ui for info, but this is being done on a VM with no GUI capabilities. What should my next step be?

*Edit*

Rather than debugging, does the fact it fails at the very end of the map run (i.e. at 97%) suggest something in particular, e.g. a corrupt file, problem writing to HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're running Hadoop on a VM, you can access it's GUI from outside the VM using its IP address. Say the VM's address is `192.168.10.10`, you can access it from outside by `192.168.10.10:50030` (job tracker).

Alternatively, you can probably access your task logs which are usually stored at `/var/log/hadoop/userlogs/`

I can't comment on why Map process stops at 97%, there isn't enough detail about that in the question

Comment: Can I ask, how do I access that when I've only got a specific part of the VM. E.g. I get given an ip address to log in to it, but running "arp -an" shows the address as 10.0.3.2. I tried using the real ip address then colon then 50030 but got nothing.

Comment: Additionally, the map job works perfectly using a locally fed file, so a bit confused about how to fit it. I've got nothing in /var/log/hadoop, it doesn't exist

Comment: Why don't you post the error message, it would give a better idea about what's going on.

Comment: There isn't one, other than the one I stated about it failing due to # of failed map jobs exceeding limit. I think it might have something to do with the multiple nodes, because I've tested it both locally and on a Hadoop with a single node. It's only with the four nodes that the problem kicks in, always at 97%